# Localize CategoryAttribute of built-in properties (e.g. Font Size or Font Family) in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, localization, attributes, propertygrid

I have a derived class, `LocalizedCategoryAttribute`, which extends the built-in `CategoryAttribute` class. This derived class overrides the `GetLocalizedString` property with a value pulled from a `.resx` file.

In the program there is a `control` with a built-in property, for example, `FontFamily`, that has been given a `LocalizedCategoryAttribute` with a key. This successfully returns the custom value for the `LocalizedCategoryAttribute` *("Fuentes de Botones" in my example)*. However, the `control` now has two category attributes - the default `CategoryAttribute`, and the custom `LocalizedCategoryAttribute`.

At the time the `PropertyGrid` chooses the category to place that `FontFamily` property in, sometimes it uses the `LocalizedCategoryAttribute` value *("Fuentes de Botones")*, while other times it uses the `CategoryAttribute` value *("Appearance")*.

I want this to consistently always be the value from the `LocalizedCategoryAttribute`.

---

I have tried changing the order of the attributes, and even of the properties. Nothing appears to be consistent enough for me to pinpoint what is causing the use of `LocalizedCategoryAttribute` vs `CategoryAttribute`. I thought it was to do with the order, as two instances of the same control, with different conditionally shown properties would cause the built-in properties like `FontFamily` to show under the "Fuentes de Botones" category, while the other instance had it showing under the "Appearance" category. All non-built-in properties work every time with the `LocalizedCategoryAttribute` value.

---

***LocalizedCategories.resx***

The .resx file has a key "ButtonFont" and value "Fuentes de Botones"

***LocalizedCategoryAttribute.cs***

```
public class LocalizedCategoryAttribute : CategoryAttribute
{
   private readonly string resourceName;
   public LocalizedCategoryAttribute(string resourceName)
   {
      this.resourceName = resourceName;
   }
   protected override string GetLocalizedString(string value)
   {
      return LocalizedCategories.ResourceManager.GetString(resourceName);
   }
}
```

***exampleControl.cs***

```
public class exampleControl : Control {
   ...

   /// <summary>Gets or sets the font family of the button</summary>
   [LocalizedCategory("ButtonFont")]
   [LocalizedDisplayName("ButtonFontFamily")]
   [LocalizedDescription("ButtonFontDescription")]
   public FontFamily FontFamily
   {
      get { return (FontFamily)GetValue(FontFamilyProperty); }
      set { SetValue(FontFamilyProperty, value); }
   }

   /// <summary>Gets or sets the color of the button's text</summary>
   [LocalizedCategory("ButtonFont")]
   [LocalizedDisplayName("ButtonTextColor")]
   [LocalizedDescription("ButtonTextColorDescription")]
   public Brush TextColor
   {
      get { return (Brush)GetValue(TextColorProperty); }
      set { SetValue(TextColorProperty, value); }
   }

   ...
}
```

***Result***
The example control shows the correctly localized display names and descriptions *(defined in different .resx files)* for both properties, but only the custom property shows up in the PropertyGrid with the localized category. The FontFamily's category is "Appearance".

Comment: Since you've tagged with wpf, what PropertyGrid control are you reffering to?

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid` - sorry for not clarifying that earlier.

Comment: exampleControl from your code is shown as expected with the two properties using the localized category value. What do you mean by " the control now has two category attributes"? FontFamily and TextColor here have only one category attribute. Or provide a reproducible sample https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example